# Faulty smart contract withdraw function

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "./SafeMath.sol";
// import "./FreezeFunction.sol";
// import "./XYZToken.sol";

contract Vault is FreezeFunction{
    // Using SafeMath to prevent underflow and overflow 
    using SafeMath for uint;
    
    mapping(address => uint256) public vaultBalance;
    mapping(address => bool) public hasDepositedEther;
    mapping(address => bool) public isStaking;  
 
    event Withdrawal(address indexed src, uint _ethAmount);
    // event Staking(address src, bool locked);

    // User deposits eth -> vaultBalance -> vaultBalance bal updates
    function depositEther(uint _ethAmount) public payable returns(bool success) {
        require(_ethAmount > 0 ether, "Cannot be 0");
 
        address(this).transfer(_ethAmount);
        vaultBalance[msg.sender] = vaultBalance[msg.sender].add(_ethAmount);

        hasDepositedEther[msg.sender] = true;
        isStaking[msg.sender] = false;
        return true;
    }
    
        // Allows user to withdraw a desired amount of eth from their vault address.
    function withdrawEther(uint _ethAmount) public returns(bool success) {
        require(vaultBalance[msg.sender] != 0, "No funds to withdraw");
        require(isStaking[msg.sender] != true, "Cannot withdraw eth while staking");
        require(vaultBalance[msg.sender] >= _ethAmount, "Not enough funds to withdraw");
        
        vaultBalance[msg.sender] = vaultBalance[msg.sender].sub(_ethAmount);
        msg.sender.transfer(_ethAmount);
        
        emit Withdrawal(msg.sender, _ethAmount);
        return true;
    }
    
    function contractBal() public view returns(uint bal) {
        bal = address(this).balance;
        return bal;
    }
    
    // Fallback function that receives ether
    receive() external payable {}
}
```

When I withdraw in remix, it doesn't add the transfer amount to the address's wallet.
Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the trouble lies in your deposit function. When you declare a method as `payable` it automatically accepts ether. Trying to transfer like this in the `depositEther` function:

```
address(this).transfer(_ethAmount);
```

Is the equivalent of saying "transfer this amount of ether from this smart contract to this smart contract". There is no need to do this since making the function `payable` will allow it to accept ether. Then you can use `msg.value` to see how much was sent in this particular function call:

```
vaultBalance[msg.sender] = vaultBalance[msg.sender].add(msg.value);
```